# Django rest delete request error "The 'file' attribute has no file associated with it. "

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using the Django rest framework for the API. I tried to make the file field optional. When I create the `instance`, it works properly, i.e., I can upload my data without a file. But when I tried to delete it, it shows the following error,

```
The 'file' attribute has no file associated with it.
```

In `models.py` file, I write as below,

```py
file = models.FileField(upload_to="%Y/%m/%d", null=True,  blank=True)
```

In `serializer.py` file, I write as below,

```py
class DataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    file = serializers.FileField(
        required=False,  allow_empty_file=True, allow_null=True)

    class Meta:
        model = DataIndex
        fields = '__all__'
```

Can anyone please help me to solve this error? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide the *full* traceback?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me. I just solved the problem and I added the answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem. Actually, the problem was from my `signals.py` file. When I checked, I found that the `post_delete` signal tried to get the file location as below,

```py
file = instance.file.path
```

I write as below and solved the problem,

```py
file = instance.file.path if instance.file else None
```